# Why does my function return the symbols instead of their values?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

Here's the code I'm working on to solve 3 equations using sympy:

```
def solvefunc(t):     # Solve for delta, beta, gamma given different t values. 
    theta = 2*t*np.sqrt(b**2+c**2+d**2)   
    delta, beta, gamma = symbols('delta beta gamma')
    eq1 = Eq(tan((delta+beta)/2),nz*tan(theta/2))
    eq2 = Eq(tan((delta-beta)/2),nx/ny)
    eq3 = Eq(cos(gamma/2),cos(theta/2)/cos((delta+beta)/2))
    result = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [delta, beta, gamma])
    fix_interval = [[remainder(j, tau) for j in i] for i in result]
    dict_output = [{'delta':i ,'beta':j ,'gamma':k } for i,j,k in fix_interval]
    locals().update(dict_output[0])
    return delta, beta, gamma
```

for each t, I can get a set of solutions `delta, beta, gamma`, they should represent numerical values, but when I get the returned results, it only shows me `(delta, beta, gamma)`. What should I do to see the values? Thanks:)

Comment: You can't alter local variables by updating `locals()`

Comment: What are `b`, `c`, `d`?  Why `np.sqrt` instead of `sympy's` function?  `nz, ny,nx`?  I was going to test your code, or atleast part of it, but it's incomplete!  Sympy expressions have `subs` and `evalf` if you want to replace symbols with other symbols or numeric values.   Your use of `locals` is bad Python style, whether it works or not.

Comment: Why not just `return *fix_interval`?

Comment: `locals().update(dict_output[0])` does nothing

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's really helpful:)